# Sub-menu's on Wordpress site won't display on hover

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I am working on a site that that is supposed to display sub-menus when you hover over both the "References" and the "Contact Us" items in the main nav. However, these items will not display.

I have tried adding hover properties via CSS to the menu & sub-menu items but nothing seems to work. It seems to always default to the "display: none;" for the sub-menu.

Here is the URL for the site: http://fongconstruction.com

I'm not sure where to go from here, if there is a CSS fix that maybe I'm missing then any guidance would be helpful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: right now those submenus *are*  immediately visible (by default, without hovering) - ??

Comment: Sorry you caught it at a time when I was trying to see if there was any way for me to show them. Right now it is not by default

Comment: and now again. makes it difficult to help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to locate a solution by using a different selector that I had not thought of before:

```
#menu-item-5990 a:hover + .sub-menu,
#menu-item-5237 a:hover + .sub-menu {
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to delete below css from custom.cs(line number 1) and style.css(line number 844) https://prnt.sc/15pru62

```
#nav .sub-menu {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Also you need to delete inline style(display: none) from sub menu https://prnt.sc/15ps03v

After that add this css

```
#nav li ul.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}

#nav li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
```